# Socket.io stops working after route change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets

**Poblem**

I have a simple Angular app with 3 routes: r1, r2, r3. The r1's controller has listeners to socket events. This is the first route that gets loaded on starting the app. Things work fine when the app is started. However, when I navigate to r2/r3 and then back to r1, sockets stop working. There is no error in the console.

**Code**

*app.js*

```
var host = "http://myhost.com";
var socket = io(host + ':3000');

angular
    .module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/r1.html',
                    controller: 'r1Ctrl'
                })
                .when('/r2', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/r2.html',
                    controller: 'r2Ctrl'
                })
                .when('/r3', {
                  templateUrl: 'views/r3.html',
                  controller: 'r3Ctrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
    });
```

*r1Ctrl.js*

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('r1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        // Listeners
        socket.on('event1', function (data) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                ...
            });
        });
        ...
});
```

Comment: probably you are refreshing the page?

Comment: you should debug a little bit more, use console.log() when socket is up etc... :P

Comment: This question seems to have gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you leave r1, the socket listener remains registered. When you visit r1 again, another listener is registered for the same event. The only explanation of your problem is that your callback is not built with that fact in mind and fails to do the work if it has already been done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think on those lines.